# Pixellib and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Всем привет, я новичок. Наткнулся на распознование объектов на фото с помощью Pixellib and Tensorflow.
Установил все зависимости, использую простой код

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

segment_image = instance_segmentation()
segment_image.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
segment_image.segmentImage("self-driving-car.jpg", show_bboxes=True, output_image_name="new.jpg")
```

Код работает без ошибок, но результат нерабочий.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:620: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
2021-12-25 12:51:51.370102: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-12-25 12:51:51.370277: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-12-25 12:51:52.650356: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_v1.py:2079: UserWarning: `Model.state_updates` will be removed in a future version. This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as `updates` are applied automatically.
  updates=self.state_updates,
Processed image saved successfully in your current working directory.
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Добавил лог, что еще сделать не понимаю.